# If $f'(z) = 0$ then $f$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is a holomorphic function on a domain $D$ in $\mathbb C$ suxh that $f'(z) = 0$ for any $z$ in $D$ and I have to show that $f$ is constant.The hint is given: use the Cauchy Riemann equations and that connectedness implies stepwise connectedness.

I don't see why the second part of the hint is of any significance. I just solved it using cauchy riemann eqns (in the most straightforward manner, I proved that the imaginary and real parts must be constant because their partial derivatives are zero).

Did I miss something?

Comment: To use "Derivatives = 0 implies constant function", you need connectedness.

Comment: @C.Dubussy why? Any link?

Comment: For instance http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927419/if-the-partial-derivatives-are-0-is-a-function-constant